# How to apply regex for Google Cloud Storage Bucket using Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am fetch objects from Google Cloud Storage using python, in the folder there are many files (around 20000).

But I just need a particular file which is .json file all other files are in csv format. For now I am using following code with prefix option:

```
from google.cloud import storage
import json
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

blobs = list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix="input"))

for blob in blobs:
    if '.json' in blob.name:
        filename = blob.name
        break
```

This process is not stable as file count is going to be increased and will take much time to filter the json file.**(file name is dynamic and could be anything)**

**Is there any option that can be used like regex filter while fetching the data from cloud storage?**

Comment: On Google Cloud, you can only filter by prefix. If you want to filter with a regex, you have to do it, on your application (like mentioned in the answer). That means, if you have 20k file and this one that you look for is the latest one listed by the API, you have to get the metadata of the 19999 files before finding yours. 20k is suitable, 20M..... So, prefix matters!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check filename/extension against a regex it's quite easy.

Just import the 're' module at the beginning

```
import re
```

And check against a regex inside the loop:

```
for blob in blobs:
    if re.match(r'\.json$',blob.name):
        filename = blob.name
        break
```

You can develop the regex at regex101.com before you burn it on your code.

BTW - I prefer to check extensions with str.endswith which is quite fast:

```py
for blob in blobs:
    if blob.name.endswith('.json'):
        filename = blob.name
        break
```

I wouldn't use

```
if '.json' in filename:
   etc...
```

because it might match anything other filenames like 'compressed.json.gz'

Comment: Thanks Inigo for this input... , could you please help me out with above scenario which I am facing ... if possible

Comment: @AshishDhamu added the answer with regexes. Hope this helps ;-)